# Creating column of 0 and 1 based on inequalities of three date columns

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I would like to create a column of 0s and 1s based on inequalities of three columns of dates.

The idea is the following. If `event_date` is before `death_date` or `study_over`, the the column `event` should be ==1, if `event_date` occurs after `death_date` or `study_over`, `event` should be == 0. Both `event_date` and `death_date` may contain NAs.

```
set.seed(1337)
rand_dates <- Sys.Date() - 365:1

df <- 
data.frame(
   event_date = sample(rand_dates, 20),
   death_date = sample(rand_dates, 20),
   study_over = sample(rand_dates, 20)
)
```

My attempt was the following

```
eventR <- 
    function(x, y, z){
    if(is.na(y)){
        ifelse(x <= z, 1, 0)
    } else if(y <= z){
        ifelse(x < y, 1, 0)
    } else {
        ifelse(x <= z, 1, 0)
    }
    }
```

I use it in the following manner

```
library(dplyr)
df[c(3, 5, 7), "event_date"] <- NA #there are some NA in .$event_date
df[c(3, 4, 6), "death_date"] <- NA #there are some NA in .$death_date

df %>%
mutate(event = sapply(.$event_date, eventR, y = .$death_date, z = .$study_over))
##Error: wrong result size (400), expected 20 or 1
##In addition: There were 40 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

I can't figure out how to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your description seems slightly inconsistent (to me) *"before death_date **or** study_over"* its one, and *"occurs after death_date **or** study_over"* it is zero. Is it possible that it could be before death_rate but after study_over? If so ,then what value should it take

Comment: @user20650 I couldn't figure out how to hard-code it into the function. Fixed it in post with df[is.na(event), "event"] <- 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would seem to construct a binary column (with NA's where needed) where 1 indicates "event_date is before death_date or study_over" and 0 is used elsewhere. As already pointed out your specification does not cover all cases:

```
df$event <- with(df, as.numeric( event_date < pmax( death_date , study_over) ) )
df
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use `pmap_dbl()` from the purrr package instead of sapply...

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% mutate(event = pmap_dbl(list(event_date, death_date, study_over), eventR))

event_date death_date study_over event
1  2016-10-20 2017-01-27 2016-12-16     1
2  2016-10-15 2016-12-12 2017-01-20     1
3        <NA>       <NA> 2016-10-09    NA
4  2016-09-04       <NA> 2016-11-17     1
5        <NA> 2016-10-13 2016-06-09    NA
6  2016-07-21       <NA> 2016-04-26     0
7        <NA> 2017-02-21 2016-07-12    NA
8  2016-07-02 2017-02-08 2016-08-24     1
9  2016-06-19 2016-09-07 2016-04-11     0
10 2016-05-14 2017-03-13 2016-08-03     1
11 2017-03-06 2017-02-05 2017-02-28     0
12 2017-03-10 2016-04-28 2016-11-30     0
13 2017-01-10 2016-12-10 2016-10-27     0
14 2016-05-31 2016-06-12 2016-08-13     1
15 2017-03-03 2016-12-25 2016-12-20     0
16 2016-04-01 2016-11-03 2016-06-30     1
17 2017-02-26 2017-02-25 2016-05-12     0
18 2017-02-08 2016-12-08 2016-10-14     0
19 2016-07-19 2016-07-03 2016-09-22     0
20 2016-06-17 2016-06-06 2016-11-09     0
```

You might also be interested in the dplyr function, `case_when()` for handling many if else statements.